# Sorting dates with python

Tags: python, sorting, datetime, iso8601

I have a list of strings like below.

```
>>> mylist = ["2013-09-07T11:23:43", "2013-09-05T15:14:12", "2013-10-13T22:06:22", "2013-11-16T23:01:34", "2013-12-22T23:11:54"]
```

I want to sort these as they are dates.

```
>>> mylist.sort()
```

This seems to work as I would like but will this always work with any date in this format?

```
>>> mylist
['2013-09-05T15:14:12', '2013-09-07T11:23:43', '2013-10-13T22:06:22', '2013-11-16T23:01:34', '2013-12-22T23:11:54']
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, that works with any date in that format, because they are:

1. using the same length, zero-padded numbers
2. in the same order
3. ordered by most significant to least significant; year, month, day, hour, minute, second

This makes them lexicographically orderable, which is exactly the order sorting would apply.